Cypress failed to start - Missing library or dependency Docker
I am trying to run Cypress in a Docker container on my M1 Pro system, but I encounter an error indicating that Cypress failed to start. The error message suggests that this may be due to a missing library or dependency. Here are the details of the error:
docker run --rm  -e BASE_URL=http://host.docker.internal:3000/  -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:13.11.0

Error Message
[STARTED] Task without title.
[FAILED] Cypress failed to start.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Please refer to the error below for more details.
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] [13:0614/074836.944798:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] <--- Last few GCs --->
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] [13:0x2c001a4000]       52 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 0.6 (1.9) -> 0.6 (1.4) MB, 0.58 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.242, current mu = 0.051) last resort; GC in old space requested
[FAILED] [13:0x2c001a4000]       53 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 0.6 (1.4) -> 0.6 (1.4) MB, 0.64 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.141, current mu = 0.021) last resort; GC in old space requested
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] <--- JS stacktrace --->
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] #
[FAILED] # Fatal JavaScript out of memory: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST
[FAILED] #
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] ----------
[FAILED] 
[FAILED] Platform: linux-arm64 (Debian - 12.5)
[FAILED] Cypress Version: 13.11.0
Cypress failed to start.

This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

Please refer to the error below for more details.

----------

[13:0614/074836.944798:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory

<--- Last few GCs --->

[13:0x2c001a4000]       52 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 0.6 (1.9) -> 0.6 (1.4) MB, 0.58 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.242, current mu = 0.051) last resort; GC in old space requested
[13:0x2c001a4000]       53 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 0.6 (1.4) -> 0.6 (1.4) MB, 0.64 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.141, current mu = 0.021) last resort; GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal JavaScript out of memory: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST
#

----------

Platform: linux-arm64 (Debian - 12.5)
Cypress Version: 13.11.0

How can I resolve the missing dbus dependency issue and get Cypress running in Docker ?

Here are several things to check:

XQuartz is installed

brew install --cask xquartz

# then logout / log in or restart your computer


XQuartz is running and allows connections from the network

open -a XQuartz

Then make sure the checkbox from the XQuartz preferences Allow connections from network clients is checked


Allow all hosts to connect to XQuartz

xhost +


Make sure to pass or set the environment variable DISPLAY in your Docker container and that your entrypoint is set to cypress

docker run \
  --rm  \
  -e BASE_URL=http://host.docker.internal:3000/  \
  -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 \
  -v $PWD:/e2e \
  -w /e2e \
  --entrypoint=cypress \
  cypress/included:13.11.0 open


References:

https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/05/02/run-cypress-with-a-single-docker-command#Interactive-mode

